# Can g-wan web server be configured with https

Tags: https, g-wan

Can anyone suggest how can g-wan be configured with secure http (https)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before G-WAN releases it SSL/TLS support, you can use [Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) which will relay SSL/TLS connections to G-WAN.

There's also another way to support `SSL/TLS` that G-WAN v3.10+ will offer: `protocol handlers`.

These handlers are dedicated to the task of supporting new protocols, like `POP3, SMTP, LDAP, XMPP.`

Instead of hard-coding al the protocols requested by our G-WAN users, we have found that it would be far better to let people implement what they actually need. We can help them to do that, but this is way to proceed is no longer blocking anyone - on either side.

So, to answer to your question, you will be able to use `OpenSSL` or `GNU-TLS` to add `SSL/TLS` support to G-WAN.

Of course, G-WAN will not be liable for the bugs in either the handlers or the SSL libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have been following G-WAN project for more than a year now.

The author of G-WAN has already built the https feature but have not released it yet. (For security reason since there's no good tool to fully test https.)

The next version will be released this month. It's a popular request so let's hope that the new version will have https.

Comment: But http://gwan.ch/archives/gwan_linux.pdf says that HTTPS is a supported protocol. (page 9)

Comment: The author already built the feature but doesn't doesn't show how to use it since its not fully tested yet when the last version is released. I suggest you wait for the next version. (It will be released this month)